# Terraform : I get "Invalid index" when I use a map and for_each to try to create some lambdas

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

I’m triying to use a map with for_each for created some lambdas, this lambdas has diferents configurations, and one is the argument "layers", I mean, that some lambdas will has 3 layers, others 2 layers, others 1 layer and finally others nothing layer, I try to test only with the lambdas that has 1 layer, but I get this error:

```
 Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on modules/lm/main.tf line 31, in resource "aws_lambda_function" "lml3":
│   31:   layers        = each.value.layer1 == "null" ? null : aws_lambda_layer_version.lm[each.value.layer1].arn
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_lambda_layer_version.lm is object with 1 attribute "capa-openpyxl-s3fs-xlrd-fsspec"
│     │ each.value.layer1 is list of string with 1 element
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: string required.
```

terraform_version": "1.4.1"
provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v4.67.0

variables.tf

```
### Global variables ###
variable "stack_id" {
  type = string
}
variable "vpc_id" {
  type = string
}

### Lambda variables ###
variable "lambda_function_l3" {
  type = map(object({
    memory_size = number,
    runtime     = string,
    handler     = string,
    s3_key      = string,
    role        = string
    layer1      = optional(list(string)),
    env_key = map(any)

  }))
}

variable "layers" {
  type = map(any)
}
```

main.tf (lambdas)

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lml3" {
  for_each      = var.lambda_function_l3
  s3_bucket     = aws_s3_bucket.lm.id
  s3_key        = "code/${each.value.s3_key}"
  function_name = "lm-${var.stack_id}-${each.key}"
  role          = aws_iam_role.lm[each.value.role].arn
  handler       = "index.${each.value.handler}"
  runtime       = each.value.runtime
  memory_size   = each.value.memory_size
layers = each.value.layer1 == "null" ? null :aws_lambda_layer_version.lm[each.value.layer1].arn 
  depends_on = [ aws_lambda_layer_version.lm ]
  environment {
    variables = each.value.env_key
  }
  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids         = [local.subnet_private[0], local.subnet_private[5]]
    security_group_ids = ["sg-0591b309a73f15dd4"]
  }
}
```

main.tf(layers)

```
locals {
  configuration_layer = merge([
    for key, values in var.layers : {
      for layer in values.filename :
      "${layer}" =>
      merge(values, {
        layer = layer
      })
    }
  ]...)
}

resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "lm" {
  for_each                 = local.configuration_layer
  filename                 = "${path.module}/layers/${each.key}.zip"
  layer_name               = "lm-layer-${var.stack_id}-${each.value.layer}"
  compatible_runtimes      = [each.value.compatible_runtimes]
  compatible_architectures = [each.value.compatible_architectures]
}
```

terraform.tfvars

```
layers = {
  "layers-lm-test-01" = { filename = ["capa-openpyxl-s3fs-xlrd-fsspec"], compatible_runtimes = "python3.9", compatible_architectures = "x86_64" }
}
lambda_function_l3 = {
  "test-01" = { memory_size = 512, runtime = "python3.9", handler = "lambda_handler", s3_key = "test_lm.zip", role = "s3_rw", layer1 = ["capa-openpyxl-s3fs-xlrd-fsspec"], env_key = { house = "car", test2 = "apple" } }
```

Comment: You seem to have omitted half of the error message. Can you edit your question to include the rest of it, so it's clearer what exactly the error message is referring to? The full error message starts with `│ Error:`

Comment: @MartinAtkins I am sorry, You are right, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you saw is correct that it isn't valid to use a list as a lookup key for a map, because in Terraform map keys are always individual strings.

If your goal is for the `layers` function of `aws_lambda_function` to include the ARN of each layer indicated in the `layers1` list then one way to write that would be:

```
  layers = (
    each.value.layer1 != null ?
    [ for k in each.value.layer1 : aws_lambda_layer_version.lm[k].arn ] :
    null
  )
```

This [`for` expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for) takes each element of `each.value.layer1` and uses it to look up one instance of `aws_lambda_layer_version.lm` with a matching key, and then takes the `arn` attribute of that object.

This will succeed only if all of the values given in `layer1` correspond with keys in `var.layers`, which doesn't seem to be true in the example `terraform.tfvars` file you shared, but does seem to be assumed by what you tried on your first attempt.

---

Note that your declaration of `variable "layers"` is incorrect, because your module clearly *cannot* accept "any element type": we can see in the definition of `local.configuration_layer` that your module requires a `filename` attribute, and in your `resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "lm"` the module requires `compatible_runtimes`, and `compatible_architectures` attributes.

Therefore the correct declaration for that variable would be:

```
variable "layers" {
  type = map(object({
    filename                 = string
    compatible_runtimes      = string
    compatible_architectures = string
  }))
}
```

Specifying your type constraints correctly will help Terraform give you better suggestions when you make a mistake.

(Given the names I'd also expect `compatible_runtimes` and `compatible_architectures` to either be `set(string)` or `list(string)`, but I see that your module expects to be given only a single one and then wraps it in a collection itself, so I wrote a type constraint compatible with how your module is currently written.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I change my code with your suggestions and that is work fine with lambdas that has layers but when I try to use "null" for lambdas that doesnt have layers I get this error:             Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on modules/lm/main.tf line 31, in resource "aws_lambda_function" "lml3":
│   31:   layers        = (each.value.layer1 != null ? [ for k in each.value.layer1 : aws_lambda_layer_version.lm[k].arn ] : null)│     │ aws_lambda_layer_version.lm is object with 3 attributes
│ 
│ Can't use a null value as an indexing key.

Comment: From that error it seems that you've set `layer1` to a list containing a `null` element, rather than making that entire attribute be `null` itself, and so Terraform thinks you are asking it to evaluate `aws_lambda_layer.version.lm[null].arn`, which is invalid.

Comment: Ok, please could you give a idea? how can I do that?

Comment: I can't see your updated `.tfvars` file but I guess you've written `layer1 = [null]` (a list containing a null value) instead of `layer1 = null` (the list itself is null)